# convert Unicode string to Decimal - Python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I'm writing a GAE project with webapp2. 
I need to convert a unicode string to Decimal value.

I receive *lat* from client side like this:

```
lat = self.request.get('lat')
```

In debugger I can see that `lat` is received and is like that: `u'50.41688620000001'` but any tries to convert it fails.
I'm converting like that:

```
edit = Decimal(lat)
```

The error is the following: *InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: ''* 
BUT: 
when I write explicitly

```
lat = u'50.41688620000001'
```

instead of

```
lat = self.request.get('lat')
```

converting works fine both with Decimal and float. ***What could be the problem?***

**EDIT:**
When I write

```
lat = self.request.get('lat')
print lat
```

this prints in the console 
two lines: one empty(have suggestions but not sure yet why exactly) and the second is actually `50.41688620000001`.

So when `Decimal(lat)` is processed it takes empty value first.

**EDIT2:** 
I realized the actual problem after some time of sitting. 
I called this server function which converts values from two jquery ajax functions. One did send *lat* to server and the other didn't but did some other work. As the function was called twice,  `self.request.get('lat')` was assigned values also twice: one empty and the other as expected - a Unicode value. So while converting and bumping into empty value, the error of empty string arised: *InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: ''*

Comment: Why not `float(lat)`

Comment: I've tried float also, but it also gives an error: *ValueError: could not convert string to float*

Comment: If that's the error you're getting, this isn't the string you're trying to convert. Post the real string.

Comment: Also what are you getting after `ValueError: could not convert string to float` ... If you are reading  `lat` from some where then it might have a non-numeral character

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error; the sample you gave works **just fine** when passed to `Decimal()`.. Can you give us the *real* string you are seeing the error with? Use `print repr(lat)`.

Comment: I;ve edited my question, please read my edit

Comment: @Elena: Are you saying that the string value *includes the text `lat = u'...'`*? So *with* the quotes and the assignment as part of the string value?

Comment: @Elena: your error message tells you are passing in an **empty string**; it is included in the error message. `Invalid literal for Decimal: ''`; the two single quotes at the end is what was passed in and could not be converted.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, I'm saying that the content of *lat* value is *u'50.41688620000001'*. No other text, just this Unicode string

Comment: @Elena: look closely at the error message. That's not what throws the exception.

Comment: @Elena your edit suggests `lat = self.request.get('lat')` is not giving back what you expect it to give back. Validate you're getting back the result you're hoping for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message is very clear:

```
Invalid literal for Decimal: ''
#                            ^^
```

It tells you that the empty string (`''`) is not a valid literal for a `Decimal()` object. Your `lat` value is not what is causing this problem here; *that* value works just fine:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> lat = u'50.41688620000001'
>>> Decimal(lat)
Decimal('50.41688620000001')
```

In the `webapp2` framework `self.request.get('lat')` will return an empty string if the `lat` parameter is *not present* in the URL GET parameters. See [*Request Data*](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html):

> By default, `get()` returns the empty string (`''`) if the requested argument is not in the request.

You probably want to guard against that, or retrieve a sensible default instead:

```
lat = self.request.get('lat', '0.0')  # provide a default
```

or

```
lat = self.request.get('lat')
if not lat:
    # return an error message, as lat is missing or empty
```

or

```
lat = self.request.get('lat')
if lat:
    # lat is provided, parse it to a Decimal
    lat = Decimal(lat)
```

Comment: I'm using webapp2 and i've written it at the very top)

Comment: @Elena: ah, yes, so you did.

Comment: I've edited the question, now I'll try to find out what does the returned value of *self.request.get('lat')* looks like exactly. In docs unfortunately I haven't found detailed info what type the returned value is. I mean dictionary or smth else.

Comment: In the end I used the 3d your suggestion. Thanks a lot for your help!!! This's a straightforward and clear solution, don't know why I didn't come to it myself. I'm very new to programming yet and really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
lat = u'50.41688620000001'

print(float(lat.encode("ascii","ignore")))
```

OR

```
def unicodeTofloat(unicode):
    unicode=str(unicode)
    ret=0.0
    integer=unicode[:unicode.find('.')]
    decimal=unicode[unicode.find('.')+1:]
    ii=1
    for i in integer:
        ret += int((10**(len(integer)-ii))*int(i))
        ii+=1
    ii=-1
    for i in decimal:
        i=int(i);
        ret += (i*(10**ii))
        ii-=1
    return ret;

lat = u'50.41688620000001'
print(str(unicodeTofloat(lat)))
```

OR

```
lat = u'50.41688620000001'
print(float(str(lat)))
```

Comment: It works **without** encoding too. The OP hasn't given us the *real* problematic value.

Comment: The error message shows that the OP passed in an *empty string*.

Comment: @Fire360Boy, thanx very much for the answer, I appreciate it. I've found the actual reason of error and described it in the EDIT2.

Comment: This is *way overkill*. The problem doesn't exist, you can just use `float(lat)` or `Decimal(lat)` **provided there is data there to convert**. Your conversion method also won't handle numbers using scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this?

```
edit = Decimal(lat or 0)
```

If "lat" is falsy (an empty string, None) it returns the part behind "or", in this case 0. So if "lat" is an empty string, "lat or 0" translates to 0. And as such the expression translates to "Decimal(0)".

Comment: Add a description of your code so that users that visit this post can understand it.